# Dynamic JComboBox content based on the contents of another JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

This code is sloppy, I would also welcome some feedback on it.

I'm trying to change the value of a JComboBox based on the value of another JComboBox. There is an additional complication in that I'm using an additional class to determine what array of strings to return (see my previous question).

In theory, the code I have should work:

```
    String[] siteSelectStrings = {"Site", "London", "Long Island"};
    JComboBox regSiteSelectBox = new JComboBox(siteSelectStrings);
    regSiteSelectBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent arg0) {
            getBuildingList gbl = new getBuildingList();
            regBuildingSelectBox.addItem(gbl.buildingSelectList((String)(regSiteSelectBox.getSelectedItem())));
            }
        });
    regSiteSelectBox.setBounds(24, 336, 282, 20);
    contentPane.add(regSiteSelectBox);


    regBuildingSelectBox = new JComboBox();
    regBuildingSelectBox.setBounds(24, 367, 282, 20);
    contentPane.add(regBuildingSelectBox);
```

And the method for returning the Building array:

```
public class getBuildingList {

public String[] buildingSelectList(String site)
{
    switch (site)
    {
    case "London":
        return new String[]  {"Building", "Harvell", "LYNX Complex", "Caroline", "Salters"};
    case "Long Island":
        return new String[] {"Building", "Phillips", "Pascal"};
    }
    return new String[] {"Failed to populate buildings"};
    }  
}
```

But, instead of returning a legible string, it returns the following:

`[Ljava.lang.String;@917081d`

I have no idea how to decode that, although it seems like a memory reference. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: In order for us to help you, you have to provide us the `getBuildingList.buildingSelectList(String arg)` method as it seems that this is the part where something gets messed up... And you should really get used to start class names with an uppercase letter, because otherwise it gets very confusing for someone else reading your code

Comment: @Raven I tend to name classes in the format [LC][UC+] wherever they are used as sub-objects, rather than primary classes - there's a  methodology that supports this, although it's not Java based. I'm technically a C# programmer...

Comment: Okay then... But we still need that method ;)

Comment: @Raven please see my edit

Comment: Does your second combobox display `[Ljava.lang.String;@917081d`?

Comment: @Raven Yes. Additionally, it displays a second list object of[Ljava.lang.String;@<value> - the value succeeding the @ symbol changes, which is why I assume it is a memory pointer. The number of entries matches the number of strings in the corresponding array.

Answer (score 2):

If you method is returning an Array of Strings to be displayed in the combo box, then you need to create a new ComboBoxModel to add to the combo box.

For example:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.*;

public class ComboBoxTwo extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
    private JComboBox<String> mainComboBox;
    private JComboBox<String> subComboBox;
    private Hashtable<String, String[]> subItems = new Hashtable<String, String[]>();

    public ComboBoxTwo()
    {
        String[] items = { "Select Item", "Color", "Shape", "Fruit" };
        mainComboBox = new JComboBox<String>( items );
        mainComboBox.addActionListener( this );

        //  prevent action events from being fired when the up/down arrow keys are used
        mainComboBox.putClientProperty("JComboBox.isTableCellEditor", Boolean.TRUE);
        add( mainComboBox );

        //  Create sub combo box with multiple models

        subComboBox = new JComboBox<String>();
        subComboBox.setPrototypeDisplayValue("XXXXXXXXXX"); // JDK1.4
        add( subComboBox );

        JButton arrow = SwingUtils.getDescendantOfType(JButton.class, subComboBox, "Text", "");
        Dimension d = arrow.getPreferredSize();
        System.out.println(arrow.getClass());
        System.out.println(d);
        d.width = 100;
        arrow.setPreferredSize(d);

        String[] subItems1 = { "Select Color", "Red", "Blue", "Green" };
        subItems.put(items[1], subItems1);

        String[] subItems2 = { "Select Shape", "Circle", "Square", "Triangle" };
        subItems.put(items[2], subItems2);

        String[] subItems3 = { "Select Fruit", "Apple", "Orange", "Banana" };
        subItems.put(items[3], subItems3);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        String item = (String)mainComboBox.getSelectedItem();
        Object o = subItems.get( item );

        if (o == null)
        {
            subComboBox.setModel( new DefaultComboBoxModel() );
        }
        else
        {
            subComboBox.setModel( new DefaultComboBoxModel( (String[])o ) );
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        try
        {
//          UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        }
        catch (Exception e) { }
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SSCCE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( new ComboBoxTwo() );
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Is recreating the model entirely necessary? I tried iterating through the items in the array, and this worked apart from the fact that it iterated through the array twice. This feels... very complex. Why is it necessary?

Comment: @Wolfish, Recreating the model keeps the solution very simple. Each set of data has its own model. The data could come from anywhere. It could be hardcoded. It could come from a database. If could come from a flat file. The solution is very reusable.

Answer (score 1):

Okay as far as I can see it your problem is that you are adding the complete array of Strings as one item. The JCombobox then converts it to a single String by invoking the `toString()` mehtod which causes it to display `[Ljava.lang.String;@917081d`.
In order for the content of your array to be displayed as single entries in the `JComboBox` you have to clear it and then add each item seperately:

```
regBuildingSelectBox.removeAllItems();

for(String currentEntry : gbl.buildingSelectList((String)(regSiteSelectBox.getSelectedItem())) {  
        regBuildingSelectBox.addItem(currentEntry);
}
```

And as you asked for additional feedback on your code... I'd suggest using enums instead of hard coded String arrays. That's just a potential error source